Can't refresh Recycler view on touch down and up event in android
I have got a problem on recycler view please help!
I added image view into recycler view and implememnt Touch event. My purpose is changed image on  imgView when touch and change back when release. My problem if I use notifyDataSetChange() on ACTION_DOWN case then ACTION_UP ignored when I release button. If remove notifyDataSetChange() on ACTION_DOWN all is OK. following code:
public class swViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnTouchListener {

        private ImageView swImg;

        public swViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            swImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sw_img);
            swImg.setOnTouchListener(this);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch (motionEvent.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.e("touch", "press - " + getBindingAdapterPosition());
                    swImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.on_button_red_transp);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    return true;


                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.e("touch", "unpress - " + getBindingAdapterPosition());
                    swImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.off_button_transp);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
        
    } 

resolved my problem ...
